# MahApps Metro Badge in MetroCircleButton

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro, badge

If I try to place a badge around the contents of a MetroCircleButton the margin is too large and does not seem to belong to that button.

```
  <Controls:Badged Width="45"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            BadgePlacementMode="BottomRight"                            
            Margin="0,0,200,0"
            Badge="3">

         <Button
            x:Name="btnModificaciones"
            Width="45"
            Height="45"              
            BorderBrush="#FF060606"
            Click="btnModificaciones_Click"
            Cursor="Hand"
            Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">

                <iconPacks:PackIconFontAwesome
                    Width="20"
                    Height="20"
                    Foreground="#FF080808"
                    Kind="Wrench" />
         </Button>

</Controls:Badged>
```

[badge in metrocirclebutton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvh9F.png)

Comment: dont use mahapps, it is so slow. switch to modernui

Comment: mahapps has many more options and I do not think it's slow

Comment: Yeah, I gotta admit, I like the textboxes with place holder, but it was slow on my project. It was a basic School Officers Voting System

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative `Padding` to move the badge closer to the `Button`:

```
<Controls:Badged Width="45"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            BadgePlacementMode="BottomRight"                            
            Margin="20"
            Padding="0 0 -10 -10"
            Badge="3">

    <Button
            x:Name="btnModificaciones"
            Width="45"
            Height="45"              
            BorderBrush="#FF060606"
            Cursor="Hand"
            Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">

        <iconPacks:PackIconFontAwesome
                    Width="20"
                    Height="20"
                    Foreground="#FF080808"
                    Kind="Wrench" />
    </Button>

</Controls:Badged>
```